# HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host what it returns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httpcontext

I have a local application which has a path:

```
http://localhost:950/m/pages/Searchresults.aspx?search=knife&filter=kitchen
```

but when this goes to integration environment or perhaps the production, it will be something like

```
http://www.someshopping.com/m/pages/SearchResults.aspx?search=knife&filter=kitchen
```

For some cases I need to pass just:

```
www.someshopping.com
```

to my XSLT file and in one of the function I'm using this:

```
string currentURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
```

this returns me "**localhost**" in local environment. Will the same code return me:

**[www.someshopping.com](http://www.someshopping.com)** in production  (I DO NOT need **http://**)

just don't want to take any chance. So asked this silly question.

Comment: maybe should be `string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes, as long as the url you type into the browser www.someshopping.com and you aren't using url rewriting then

```
string currentURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
```

will return `www.someshopping.com`

Note the difference between a local debugging environment and a production environment

Comment: It returns 'HOSTNAME' header or local address if the header is not present. See sources for details: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRequest.cs,36cdd1ccad69cf75

Answer (score 20):

The `Host` property will return the domain name you used when accessing the site. So, in your development environment, since you're requesting

```
http://localhost:950/m/pages/Searchresults.aspx?search=knife&filter=kitchen
```

It's returning `localhost`. You can break apart your URL like so:

```
Protocol: http
Host: localhost
Port: 950
PathAndQuery: /m/pages/SearchResults.aspx?search=knight&filter=kitchen
```

Comment: So my question goes will this return www.someshopping.com in production environment ? :)

Comment: Yes it will, assuming the URL you are requesting in production is www.someshopping.com.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
string callbackurl = Request.Url.Host != "localhost" 
    ? Request.Url.Host : Request.Url.Authority;
```

This will work for local as well as production environment. Because the local uses url with port no that is possible using Url.Host.

Comment: you should always use `Request.IsLocal` to check if it's a local request, no need to compare the `Request.Url.Host` as that's false if I actually write `http://LocalHost/...`